# A lot of viedoes on web site

Tags: html, web, video

Suppose I want to develop a web site with a lot of videos, since there will be a lot of videos I will need a lot of space in the server-side, how can I store a large number of videos for the website?

I mean, for playing a video I need to write in the HTML tag a relative path, like: `~/MySite/Videos/video1.mp4`, but since I will have a lot of videos I thought to put all videos on external USB's with a lot of space.

how can I tell the HTML to navigate to the USB drive, how to approach this issue?

Comment: your webserver will need to be able to the path where your videos are as something relative to the root if you want just just serve them as www.mysite.com/videos/video1.mp4 - so a symlink or alias to put the drive where you need it would be easiest. You could also have a handler (in php or some other scripting language) that reads them from a non-visible path and then delivers them (but that's not as easy)

Comment: Put the html file on the usb drive in `mysite` folder. Html file loads video path as: `<video src="Videos/video1.mp4>`

Comment: @VC.One I thought about that, but let's say I want to read viedos from muliplte usb's the I have a problem.

Comment: If you need to add usb drives to a server to add space, you have the wrong server. One option is to look at a dedicated media server or CDN

Answer (score 0):

> *"...Let's say I want to read videos from multiple usb's then I have a problem."*

You can try the [**`file` protocol**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa767731(v%3Dvs.85)) (for local machine files, instead of online loading via  `https` protocol).

The format is: `file:///X://` (where drive *X* is your own preferred).

Example: This html could be on drive `G:` and yet be loading a video file from drive `E:`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video width="800" controls>
<source src="file:///E://VC1_files/trailer_Watchmen_HBO_01.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

</body>
</html>
```